# How to have several hue conditions with seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, categories, boxplot

I am looking for your help as a new user in python, pandas, seaborn etc.
Here is my problem : I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "M1","2020","Brut","A",0.51], 
                   [1, "M2","2020","Brut","A",0.6], 
                   [1, "M3","2020","Brut","A",0.2],
                   [1, "M1","2030","Brut","A",0.5],
                   [1, "M2","2030","Brut","A",0.6],
                   [1, "M3","2030","Brut","A",0.8],
                   [2, "M1","2020","Brut","B",1], 
                   [2, "M2","2020","Brut","B",0.4], 
                   [2, "M3","2020","Brut","B",0.3],
                   [3, "M1","2030","Brut","B",0.6],
                   [3, "M2","2030","Brut","B",0.85],
                   [3, "M3","2030","Brut","B",0.59]], 
                   columns=['Site', 'Model','Time','Type','Region','Value'])
```

which give this pandas dataframe

```
    Site Model  Time  Type Region  Value
0      1    M1  2020  Brut      A   0.51
1      1    M2  2020  Brut      A   0.60
2      1    M3  2020  Brut      A   0.20
3      1    M1  2030  Brut      A   0.50
4      1    M2  2030  Brut      A   0.60
5      1    M3  2030  Brut      A   0.80
6      2    M1  2020  Brut      B   1.00
7      2    M2  2020  Brut      B   0.40
8      2    M3  2020  Brut      B   0.30
9      3    M1  2030  Brut      B   0.60
10     3    M2  2030  Brut      B   0.85
11     3    M3  2030  Brut      B   0.59
```

What I would like to do is to have a seaborn boxplot with both Site and Region as "hue" condition.
I would like to have an indication of the region corresponding to each site. For example I would like the sites 2&3 to be link to region B.
For now, i can only succeed a simple boxplot.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
from os.path import isfile, join
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

path=r"C:\Downloads\test_seaborn.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(path,";")

fig = plt.gcf()
# Change seaborn plot size
fig.set_size_inches(20, 20)
#change seaborn x and y axis size
sns.set(font_scale=1.4)
sns.set_style("darkgrid") #format of the grid
# call boxplot function, x and y must be columns of the dataframe, part of the code to add the mean
bp=sns.boxplot(x='Site',y='Value',hue="Time", data=df)
# add a title
bp.set_title("Boxplot per site",fontdict= { 'fontsize': 24, 'fontweight':'bold'})
# set x label and y label size and name
bp.set_xlabel('Site',fontsize = 20, )
bp.set_ylabel('Value (m²/s)',fontsize = 20 )
# set legend caracteristics
bp.legend(fontsize = 20, \
               title="Time", \
               title_fontsize = 18, \
               shadow = True, \
               facecolor = 'white')
```

[image]

Any idea to help me ?

best regards
Natahn

Comment: Your value column is probably not numerical. If it were, it would show "0.123" instead of "0,123". Check your `df.dtypes`.

Comment: I plotted the first 16 values using the same commands as you, and the boxplots appear correctly. So the problem shouldn't be with your commands. It is indeed highly likely the problem comes from your data.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to transform the comma in dot ... 
thanks for that, I will change it. 
But for the second point, do you have any idea ?

Comment: What does "to have an indication of the region " mean in this context? Should the boxplot appearance differ? Should the region be mentioned by the tick labels?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks again for this question. What I mean is that I don't have a specific need for that.
The best would be to only display the sites of a same region. 
E.g in my example, I would only say in my code to display x='site', y='value', hue='time' AND 'Region
Or it could be onsly to display the sites of one specific region

Comment: Do you mean region-wise subplots? If you just wanted to indicate the region, you could combine the columns `df["SiteRegion"] = df.Site.map(str) + " in region " + df.Region`, then use this new column for all subsequent procedures To plot one region, you can use Boolean indexing: `df_plot=df[df["Region"]=="B"]`

Comment: Okay, thanks ! 
I'll try one of this option :)